# Is there a library that allows einstein summation on dense, sparse, and LinearOperator type tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, libraries, tensor

Numpy's `einsum` only works with dense tensors.

Is there an alternative that also works with sparse tensors and linear operators?

For example, I might have a function `f` that computes matrix vector multiplications of the form $A^{-1}x$ for some matrix $A$. Numpy's
`einsum` doesn't even allow

```
np.einsum('ij,j',A,x)
```

let alone

```
np.einsum('ijkl,mj->imkl',X,A)
```

The same  operations also don't work when $A$ is a sparse matrix (let alone a general sparse tensor).

While the LinearOperator support is more of a convenience question, the  support for sparse tensors is crucial to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the list at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_software) and answers to [Fast, lightweight C++ tensor library for dimension-agnostic code](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/11276). Especially [taco](https://github.com/tensor-compiler/taco) seems to fit your needs.